# Node.js indexOf sometimes breaks but only under certain conditions. Is this a V8 bug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I encountered a very strange bug when using indexOf with a large array of numbers. It is sometimes returning -1 when it shouldn't be.

I have recreated the problem with a small subset of the code. Array.prototype.indexOf appears to work as expect in all cases, not sure why this is but it is useful as a fault test.

Strangely using eval() within the function changes the behaviour of indexOf. I'm leaning towards an issue with the way V8 optimises code inside tight loops. I'm assuming eval() is simply triggering a de-optimisation within the function.

Googling the issue didn't seem to turn up any issues quite like this one. Is this a bug inside V8?

Here is the code, simply save to a file and run with "node" on the command line. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
// Run this script with Node.js to see it throw. Works fine in browsers for some reason. Maybe an optimisation bug

function loop() {
  var arr = [0];

  var i = 0;

  //eval('(1)');            // ==== UNCOMMENTING THIS MAKES IT WORK

  while (i < 4101) {        // ==== MAKING THIS SMALLER MAKES IT WORK
    var num = (i % 2) / 2;  // ==== SIMPLIFYING THIS MAKES IT WORK

    //console.log(num);

    if (arr.indexOf(num) !== Array.prototype.indexOf.call(arr, num)) {
      console.log('i', i);
      console.log('num', num);
      throw new Error('WTF this should not happen!');
    }

    i++;
  }
}

loop();
```

Edit: Anzeo has pointed out this works on v0.12.5 and I have confirmed this. I was using v0.12.2, also tried v0.10.38 and iojs-v2.0.1 which all revealed this bug. It is looking like this is a V8 issue that has been fixed in recent versions.

Comment: For posterity, what version of node are you running?

Comment: I'm running this on Windows 8 x64 node 0.12.5 and I don't get the error

Comment: This was useful. I was using v0.12.2. It appears not to occur in v0.12.5 so I'm guessing it is an issue that has been fixed very recently.

Comment: Might have found the issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=407946